# WCF Rest 4 Dependency Injection

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

There are a lot of Dependency Injection examples for Wcf, but many of them deal with versions of Wcf prior to 4.0. I have an app built with Wcf 4 Rest, no .svc file that basically looks like this.

```
public class RestService : IRestService
{
    IUserRepository _userRepo;

    public RestService(IUserRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
    public UserModel GetUser(int id)
    {
        return _repo.GetUserById(id);
    }
 }

 public interface IRestService
 {
      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          UriTemplate = "/User/{id}",
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
      UserModel GetUserById(int id);
 }
```

Like I said, no svc file, the whole nine yards. Just this in the global.asax file

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("RestService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(RestService)));
```

So, I am wanting to use Castle Windsor to inject the UserRepository.

What is the best way of setting up the service with this 4.0 implementation to utilize Castle Windsor?

Comment: I think WCF Facility supports that doesn't it?

Comment: It sure does, I've used the WCF facility in many apps, it accomplishes this quite handily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency injection in WCF isn't something which can be easily accomplished. You essentially need to implement an `IServiceProvider` which will be invoked when a new instance of the service needs to be created. You can then use Windsor or some other IoC tool to get the repository instance.

You can find an example of such IoC container in the post about instance providers at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx.

Comment: that's true, or at least unless you're using something like Windsor's WCF Facility which does bridge the WCF world with the container.